# android:gravity="center" not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#000000"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff0000">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

which has the following Design.

[image]

Shouldn't the `button` be placed in the center vertically as well? I know how the `layout_gravity` and `gravity` works. So according to my understanding the button should be definitely at the center both horizontally as well as vertically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must add `android:gravity="center"` in your `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ff0000">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this works fine. thanks. But without adding gravity="center" in the linearLayout how does it place the button in the center horizontally ?

Comment: what do you mean? You can't do it with other way. Because the LinearLayout places tha child views on an orientation you must set the gravity so it will understand where this must place them

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@vspallas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370219/androidgravity-center-not-working-as-expected/35370301#35370301) answer, I found the solution to my question. Basically the reason for this behavior is that I am specifying `vertical` orientation to my LinearLayout. It means that whatever views I place inside the `layout` should be shown in a vertical orientation i.e. one below the other. If I had three views inside my LinearLayout, then the result should be something like this

```
View1
View2
View3.
```

But if I did `android:layout_gravity="center"` for View2 and had it worked according to my expectation, then it would have placed `View2` in the center, and not between `View1` and `View3` which will contradict the `orientation` attribute. Hence Android allows to set gravity to the parent itself which will make sure that all the views inherit the same gravity and are in the same orientation for `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Yeah, so this means that layout_gravity on child and gravity on parent are not the same in some instances.